# Xserve G5 Leopard Server - How to turn off the beeping when the RAID is degraded?

Tags: raid, apple, xserve, osx-leopard

My XServe G5 is beeping constantly because of a RAID drive that has failed. We're going to get a new replacement drive tomorrow evening.

The beeping is very annoying and I was wondering if there was a way to turn it off?

I've found some articles about this on google but they all seem to be about megaraid, but I don't have a MegaRAID adapter, it's just standard RAID .

OS Leopard Server, 10.5.8

Thank you all!

Johan

Answer (score 0):

If your Xserve G5 doesn't have a MegaRAID card, then it doesn't have the capability to emit an audible alarm.

If you are convinced you don't have this card, then you're most probably hearing the failing hard disk itself. Have you tried removing the failed drive?